# Android studio logcat: How to make it multiline instead of horizontal expansion

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

I am sending a complicated json object including nested objects and arrays. Before sending it, I am trying to observe whether the json is well formed or not. So I've printed the json data in Android studio logcat. I am trying to copy the data and paste it in an online json viewer tool for inspecting such as: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Problem is- the whole data is printed in one line, so it gets difficult to copy the whole data from there. It would be more convenient if the data would be printed in multi line. Is there any way in Android studio logcat that I can omit the horizontal scroller and see everything in multi line ?

[image: The scroller is too little and I've to hold the mouse for a long time to select the whole data.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press on the focussed button. It'll wrap the text to next line

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: perfect one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: sure, but it says I can do it in 5 minutes. I will surely mark it as correct.